# Is there anything that comes after onWindowFocusChanged in the life cycle?

Tags: android, imageview

I'm using this to attain the width and height of an imageView.

```
 @Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    imageViewHeight = imageView.getHeight();
    imageViewWidth = imageView.getWidth();

//        System.out.println("Imageview -   Width: " + imageViewWidth + " " + "Height :" + imageViewHeight);
}
```

The processing in this activity that i'm going to write relies on these variables so everything has to start from here. Is that OK? I tried onCreate, onStart and onResume and they all come before onWindowFocusChanged.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I checked it is last to be called and when activity gets focus, but as per API docs it is not completely reliable. But will work in most of cases.
Also make sure to use of variable hasfocus, as when a dialog or some system level alert is displayed or your activty goes back ground, `onWindowFocusChanged` will be the fist one to be called with `hasfocus` as false. It may give some unpredictable problem.

Comment: This is what I thought, thanks. Perhaps i'll just use the size of the screen and image to work it out.